# Performing a subquery in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to convert some common queries that we use to an API call using EF Core but I can't seem to get it working.

The SQL that will typically be run will looking something like this:

```
select * 
from my_table 
where convert(date, datefield) = (select date 
                                  from another_table 
                                  where name == 'my_string')
```

My attempts at converting this into Linq have been fruitless. I've tried something like this and similar variants.

```
public async Task<my_table> GetStuff()
{
    return await _context.my_table
                         .Where(m => _context.another_table
                                             .Where(a => a.name == "my_string")
                                             .Select(a => a.date).Equals(m.updatedate)).FirstAsync();
}
```

There error I get is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<my_table>()
    .Where(t => DbSet<another_table>()
        .Where(t0 => t0.name == "my_string")
        .Select(t0 => t0.date).Equals((object)t.updatedate))' could not be translated.
```

I've seen some posts about using `Include` or joining, but these tables are not related.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try this `.Select(a => a.date == m.updatedate)` in your sub-query?

Comment: Doesn't appear so. It looks like that then returns a boolean type rather than the model type.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. You should try this `.Where(a => a.date == m.updatedate)`

Comment: Still no dice. This is what I have interpreted from your comments. Let me know if I have misunderstood: `return await _context.my_table.Where(m => _context.another_table.Where(a => a.name == "my_string").Where(a => a.date == m.updatedate)).FirstAsync();`

Comment: `return await _context.my_table.Where(m => _context.another_table.Where(a => a.name == "my_string" && a.date == m.updatedate)).FirstAsync();` let's combine 2 `Where` into 1 and debug it again

Comment: Similar error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<namespace.Models.another_table>' to 'bool'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing to mention is that even SQL allows the following

```sql
where convert(date, datefield) = (select date 
                                  from another_table 
                                  where name == 'my_string')
```

it will fail if the right subquery returns more than one result. Because in general subqueries (so is the LINQ "collections") return sequences, not single value.

So the safer and better approach would be to use either `IN`

```sql
where convert(date, datefield) in (select date 
                                  from another_table 
                                  where name == 'my_string')
```

or `EXISTS`

```sql
where exists (select * from another_table 
    where name == 'my_string' and date == convert(date, my_table.datefield))
```

Both these translate naturally to LINQ - `IN` to `Contains`

```cs
_context.my_table
    .Where(m => _context.another_table
        .Where(a => a.name == "my_string")
        .Select(a => a.date)
        .Contains(m.updatedate) // <--
    )
```

and `EXISTS` to `Any`

```cs
_context.my_table
    .Where(m => _context.another_table
        .Any(a => a.name == "my_string" && a.date == m.updatedate) // <--
    )
```

Comment: The first method using 'IN' threw an error regarding `IQueryable<DateTime>` not having a definition `Contains`. The second method using `EXIST` seems to have worked but I'm not getting a `Sequence contains no elements.` log. I'm sure it's likely that the dates aren't matching. I'll report back shortly.

Comment: The dates appear to be the same so something is amiss.

Comment: I tried using `Contains` and this is the error I'm getting now. `IQueryable<DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<DateTime?>(ReadOnlySpan<DateTime?>, DateTime?)' requires a receiver of type 'ReadOnlySpan<DateTime?>' Other posts mentioned including `System.Linq` but that didn't fix it.

Comment: There is definitely [Queryable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.contains?view=net-6.0) extension method, have you included `using System.Linq;`? But that's not essential since the two ways are equivalent / interchangeable / a matter of taste.

Comment: What about not matching, I don't know what is the type of `date` and `updatedate` properties / columns because you didn't include classes and their attributes/configuration in the question. However the `convert(date, datefield)` you used in the  shown SQL query in question makes me think they are different, or at least the `datefield` has to be truncated to date (the time portion to be removed). If that's the case, that's different question, but the EFC LINQ equivalent is `.Date` property, e.g. replace `m.updatedate` with `m.updatedate.Date` in both places.

Comment: The `date` field is a `date` datatype. The `updatedate` is a `datetime` datatype. `updatedate` is nullable, and `date` is not. I can do `a.date.Date` but doing that for the other one gives me an error `DateTime? does not contain a definition for Date`. When I select the values separately, they are equal `{3/4/2022 12:00:00 AM}`

Comment: I should add that they are different in the actual Sql tables in the database. The model types are `DateTime` and `DateTime?`.

Comment: As I said, that's different question. But anyway, you don't need to do that for the `date` type column, and for nullable one use `.Value` before `.Date`, e.g. `m.updatedate.Value.Date`. Don't worry about `null` values, this is will be translated to SQL where `NULL`s are handled naturally w/o special nullable types.

Comment: adding `Value.Date` did it. After some digging I saw that the time was indeed different. It's weird that it was showing the same, but looking deeper into the variables, the time was different on the `updatedate` column. Thank you!